# SAS - "ERROR: File ____ Does Not Exist" when running PROC SQL using new DSN connection to Azure DB

Tags: azure, sas, azure-sql-database

We have 4 DSN connections to Azure DBs:
Test A, Test B, Prod A, and Prod B

Test A, Test B, and Prod A were set up in SAS Management Console by a different Admin (no longer with the org).  All three connect and return data without issue.

I just created Prod B in Server Manager, and our Windows Server Admin created the DSN (based on the other 3 DSNs).  I used the Prod A server configuration as a guide for creating Prod B, and made sure the Datasrc points to the newly created DSN.

When running a PROC SQL ; SELECT * FROM  QUIT ; I get "Error: File ____ does not exist" for Prod B.  When I run the same script in Test B, I get the expected results.  (Similar scripts for Test A and Prod A return results as well).

I'm not sure where the error is coming from (SAS, Windows, or somewhere else).  The table with data exists in both Test B and Prod B Azure DBs, so it is not a missing DB (been asked this already).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved:

The Default database in the DSN was set to master instead of the PROD_DB.  Once this was changed, I was able to connect to the table.